# Get canvas click coordinates with css scaling and contain:fit

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html5-canvas

For my pixel art website, I have a canvas that is fixed relative to the viewport, scaled with css, and has object-fit:contain; to keep it the size of the div, no matter what is drawn or resized inside.
I need to get the mouse click coordinates **without scaling**. The scaled coordinates collected by e.y/e.x wouldn't be useful since object-fit:contain; would change aspect ratios.

Here is some dummy code to better explain my question:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("scaledCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.height = 16; // varaible height
c.width = 16; // varaible width

for (var x = 0; x < c.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < c.height; y++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16); // pick random color
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1); // draw pixel on canvas
  }
}


c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //this is what i need help with, clickX and clickY need to give the pixel coordinates of the canvas, not the screen
  let clickX = e.x - this.offsetLeft;
  let clickY = e.y - this.offsetTop;

  console.log(clickX + ", " + clickY);
}, false);
```

```css
#scaledCanvas {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="scaledCanvas" width="16" height="16">Canvas Not Supported</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it be something like that? I take the "pixel's" cell coords.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("scaledCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.height = 16; // varaible height
c.width = 16; // varaible width

for (var x = 0; x < c.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < c.height; y++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16); // pick random color
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1); // draw pixel on canvas
  }
}


c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  let realWidth = c.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let realHeight = c.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  let cellSize = (realWidth < realHeight) ? realWidth/16 : realHeight/16;

  let clickX = Math.floor((e.x - this.offsetLeft - (realWidth - cellSize*16)/2)/cellSize);
  let clickY = Math.floor((e.y - this.offsetTop - (realHeight - cellSize*16)/2)/cellSize);

  console.log(clickX + ", " + clickY);
}, false);
```

```css
#scaledCanvas {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="scaledCanvas" width="16" height="16">Canvas Not Supported</canvas>
```

Comment: I don't test the result in case of being out of the real canvas with pixels. You should add some testing: if x < 0 || x > 15, or y < 0 || y > 15 then the click is out of actual canvas.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thanks so much, i didn't know about getBoundingClientRect, that helps a ton! As for clicking off of the pixels, it's not a problem.

Comment: Main idea is to devide smaller size (width or height) on 16 parts and take half of the rest of the longest size. Only then we can find the right place of click.

Comment: if i'm correct, you would need to account for padding as well?

Comment: Sure, in fact I don't even know what `getBoundingClientRect()` is))) Just looked for any option to get the width of an HTML-element. As I said before: the case is to represent that area as a 16*16 cell field. Also to cut off the rest part of "container".